# css for a specific table header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table implemented using a third party library. There i have something like the below code when inspecting the elements.

```
<th class="" colspan="3">
   <span class="ant-table-header-column">
      <div>
          <span class="ant-table-column-title">
             GENERAL
          </span>
          <span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
      </div>
   </span>
 </th>



<th class="" colspan="2">
       <span class="ant-table-header-column">
          <div>
              <span class="ant-table-column-title">
                 INFORMATION
              </span>
              <span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
          </div>
       </span>
     </th>
```

I want to write a css class for `th` where `colspan="3"` . The `colspan="3"` part is the only difference between the code blocks. How do i write a custom class to override the css properties from the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
th[colspan="3"] {
   ...
}
```